# Cannot establish ssh connection to computer on local network

Tags: 11.10, ssh

I've just (re)installed ubuntu 11.10 on my main pc, and the connection times out every time I try to ssh connect to my laptop (over the local network) to retrieve the files I backed up there. The connection times out every time I try to connect.

I can establish a connection in the other direction without issue.

Here's the verbose output I get when I try to connect:

```
ovangle@ruby-EP43-DS3:~$ ssh -v ovangle@10.1.1.4
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.1.1.4 [10.1.1.4] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.1.1.4 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.1.1.4 port 22: Connection timed out
```

ssh is installed on both machines, and I've tried deleting '~/.ssh/known_hosts' on both machines, still nada.

I've changed the sshd logging on the laptop to VERBOSE and restarted the daemon (because I wasn't getting any relevant syslog entries otherwise), and this is the log for the most recent connection attempt.

EDIT: posted wrong logs last time. They just showed that there was a connection received, they weren't actually the sshd logs (which were in auth.log as I recently discovered). Unfortunately, that log is filling up with extremely weird error messages and it gives me no information about the connection.

```
Nov  8 16:02:18 ovangle-A6Rp pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Nov  8 16:02:18 ovangle-A6Rp pkexec: pam_ck_connector(polkit-1:session): cannot determine display-device
Nov  8 16:02:18 ovangle-A6Rp pkexec[6270]: ovangle: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/ovangle] [COMMAND=/usr/sbin/gnome-power-backlight-helper --set-brightness 2]
Nov  8 16:02:19 ovangle-A6Rp pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Nov  8 16:02:19 ovangle-A6Rp pkexec: pam_ck_connector(polkit-1:session): cannot determine display-device
Nov  8 16:02:19 ovangle-A6Rp pkexec[6273]: ovangle: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/ovangle] [COMMAND=/usr/sbin/gnome-power-backlight-helper --set-brightness 7]
```

Comment: Try to use verbose, eg. "ssh -vvv username@laptop" and post the relevant output.

Comment: Do you have `openssh-server` installed on both machines?

Comment: updated the post with the relevant output. Also, both machines have openssh-server installed.

Comment: What does sshd log on the laptop when connecting to there?

Comment: on the machine you're trying to connect to do a `sudo service ssh restart` and see what the output is.

Comment: The same happens to me, it seems that when you logoff, Network Manager closes and then you are not only unable to conect using ssh, but even to do a single ping. I am currently looking for a solution but what you can do is to just block the screen and do not logoff. This may work.

Comment: Don't you have **iptables** rules on your laptop that would prevent SSH ? Do `iptables -L` to list the rules if they are activated. If you have firewall rules activated, you must have at least one allowing traffic (ACCEPT) to TCP port 22.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you install the openssh server in the main PC (where you are trying to ssh into)

> `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

then check if the Ubuntu firewall is turne on?

> `sudo ufw status`

if yes or no still issue the following command

> `sudo ufw allow ssh` and `sudo ufw reload`

Now try to ssh using

> `ssh user@ip-address-of-the-machine`

If this doesn't work try to add the INPUT and OUTPUT firewall rule in IPTABLE

> `sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`
>
> `sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`
>
> `sudo iptables-save`
>
> `sudo service iptables restart`

You might have to restart the network manager as well.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have the ssh server running by running the below on the machine you wish to connect to:

```
service ssh status
```

If that returns start/running, process *pid* then it is running ok. If not run

```
service ssh start
```

and check the output that it starts correctly. If it is started correctly and you still can not ssh to the machine then on the remote host install nmap

```
apt-get install nmap
```

Nmap (Network Mapper) is a port scanner which is useful for this kind of stuff. Run the below on the computer you are connecting from

```
nmap *ipaddress/hostname of computer you are trying to connect to*
```

and check the 22/tcp or ssh is shown as open.

refer to [Ubuntu iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) to learn how to open the ports.